# _clearer is not a function error when running react native application

Tags: react-native

I am getting this strange error after updating to react-native 0.39.0. This is happening on both Android and iOS. I tried reverting to the previous version but I still get the same error. 
I am using react@15.4.1, react-native@0.39.0.

Surprising part is if I enable remote debug, the app works just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screen shot of the error]

Comment: I'm getting this same exact error. And just like you, no error while remotely debugging.

Comment: @AlexHarrison look at my answer for a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the error was due to react-native-firestack redefining window object, it was assigning window object with {}. I submitted a PR to fix this and it has already been merged.